# How to swap axes on boxplot when one variable is discrete and the other is continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I currently have a boxplot that looks like this in R:

[image]

However, I would like the variable "length" to be on the y-axis instead of the x-axis, and the variable "group" to be on the x-axis instead (i.e. flip the axes).

I tried the following code, with p being the formula for the boxplot on ggplot2, but I think it does not work as "group" is a discrete variable whereas "length" is a continuous variable:

```
p + scale_x_reverse()
```

Is there a way to make it work? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the x and y in the `aes()` function?

Comment: Try `coord_flip()`